# Battlefield 3 weapons statistics (damage, etc.)

Tags: battlefield-3

Is there a definitive list of weapons in Battlefield 3 with the damage they do, accuracy, etc.?

In Battlefield Bad Company 2, the game had this information available on each weapon inside the game, but there appears to be no such thing in Battlefield 3.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there is not. The only stats you'll find are the ones on Battlelog, and they're very lackluster.

It's one of the main complaints that hopefully DICE has noticed and will fix.

Answer (score 22):

**What There's Not**

Bad Company 2's in-game information was very helpful, but even that was incomplete. Den Kirson addressed that by reading the program code from the PC version and publishing [mind-blowingly awesome comparison charts](http://denkirson.xanga.com/722757523/bad-company-2/).

So far I've found nothing so comprehensive for BF3. Unfortunately the official Prima game guide doesn't provide much more statistical information—if any—than you get in-game.

**What There Is**

However, through [Donncha's blog](http://xeer2000.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/battlefield-3-weapon-damage/) I found [this Google Docs spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0Ag42gMGK9WrwdHRfa0JhdW9TR1E0bjBueWVSQjc0V0E&f=true&noheader=true&gid=11) from the "ESDECO Battlefield Research Consortium" (BRC), which has a good deal of information.

It doesn't provide nearly as much as Kirson's charts so far. For example, it doesn't yet have the important accuracy-affecting factors of spread, spray, and recoil. But if it's correct as far as it goes, it's at least a useful start. On the various tabs you can find:

- Damage per shot
- Suppressed bullet damage
- Time to Kill
- Rounds to Kill

**Methodology Caveat**

Note that whereas Kirson derived his raw data from the game code, the BRC researchers got theirs empirically by shooting each other. (Now that's dedication to research. :-)

Below are the current **damage** results at 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 40 meters:

#### Assault

```
M16A3    25  25  24  23  22  20  19
AK-74M   25  25  24  23  22  20  19
M416     25  25  24  23  22  20  19
AEK-971  25  25  24  23  22  20  19
M16A4    25  25  24  23  22  20  19
F2000    25  25  24  21  20  20  19
AN-94    25  25  24  23  22  20  19
G3A3     34  34  33  32  31  29  28
KH2002   25  25  24  23  22  20  19
M26 Slg  50  46  37  32  31  31  31
```

#### Engineer

```
A-91     25  25  24  22  21  19  17
AKS-74u  25  25  24  23  20  19  18
M4A1     25  25  24  22  21  19  16
SCAR-H   34  34  32  28  26  26  22
SG553    25  25  24  22  21  19  16
G36c     25  25  24  22  21  19  17
```

(Note that DICE has already said SCAR-H is scheduled for nerf, it's a huge outlier here, even with a small 21 round magazine.)

#### Support

```
M27 IAR       25  25  25  24  23  22  20  19
RPK-74M       25  25  25  24  23  22  20  19
M249          25  25  25  24  23  22  20  19
PKP Pecheneg  34  34  34  33  32  31  29  25
M240B         34  34  34  33  32  31  29  28
M60E4         34  34  34  33  32  28  26  25
TYPE 88 LMG   25  25  25  24  23  23  19  18
```

#### Recon

```
SV98      75  75  75  75  73  68  66  61  56  55  55
SVD       50  50  49  48  47  44  43  41  38  34  34
MK11 Mod  50  50  49  48  47  44  43  41  38  34  34
SKS       34  34  34  34  33  32  32  30  30  30  28
M39 EMR   50  50  49  48  47  44  43  41  38  34  34
```

(Recon results, due to the extended range, also include 50m, 60m, 80m, 100m)

#### Pistols

```
M9         30  29  25  19  15  12  12
G17C       30  29  23  19  16  12  12
MP412 Rex  50  50  40  34  32  18  16
G17C Sup   30  29  25  21  17  13  13
M9 Sup     30  29  25  21  17  13  12
MP443 Sup  30  29  25  21  17  13  13
G18        20  20  18  15  15  13  13
.44 Mag    55  51  51  46  41  28  24
G18 Sup    20  20  18  16  15  13  13
MP443      30  30  25  21  17  13  13
M1911      34  34  31  25  19  13  13
M1911 Sup  34  34  31  23  19  13  13
M93        20  20  17  15  13  13  13
M9 Tac     30  29  25  21  17  12  12
MP443 Tac  30  29  25  21  16  12  12
M1911 Tac  34  34  31  25  17  12  12
```

#### All Kit

```
PP-2000  25  25  22  20  17  12  10
UMP-45   25  24  22  19  16  13  13
MP7      17  17  16  15  14  10  10
PDW-R    25  25  22  20  17  15  14
P90      17  17  16  15  14  11  10
```

Not factored in here is rate of fire, amount of recoil, accuracy, magazine size, reload times, etcetera. [Please see the full spreadsheet](http://xeer2000.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/battlefield-3-weapon-damage/) for Time to Kill and other important metrics.

I'm not sure which method to trust more. With empirical data you can have observation error, and there could be damage bonuses/penalties in play that you're not aware of and so can't factor in to your numbers. On the other hand, depending on how thoroughly you read the game code you might also overlook damage bonuses and penalties.

Either way, it's interesting data.

Comment: it's not really possible to read the server side game code, though. That's my understanding.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I hadn't heard that. I just assumed Den found it in the client-side code, but I suppose it makes more sense for weapon info to be on the server. I'm almost curious enough to fire up a decompiler and look at the client code. Almost. :-) (BTW, thanks for importing the stat tables.)

Comment: Are these stats pre-Return-To-Karkand?  Have they changed?

Comment: @GWLlosa, the stats are pre-RTK. Unfortunately I don't know whether they've changed. Your best bet is to check the source spreadsheet linked above (see "this Google Docs spreadsheet").

Answer (score 14):

Weapon statistics have now been ripped from the game files. See all the statistics and graphs here:
http://symthic.dy.fi/?s=bf3

Comment: Are these stats pre-Return-To-Karkand?  Have they changed?

Comment: These have been updated to include the latest patch. (April 2012)

Comment: The stats are updated at each patch. Battlefield 4's section is currently being updated and prepared for more data as well.

Answer (score 3):

I've gone through dozens of sites, and by far the best chart I've found is [here](http://symthic.com/?s=bf3).  It not only gives **damage of each weapon as a function of distance**, like @Drew's chart, but also gives:

- **Rate of fire**
- **Bullet speed**
- **Supression amount**
- **Magazine size**
- **Maximum range**
- **Reload time**, including partial-reload times, and a special threshold (which I didn't know existed) which makes cancelled-reloads reload faster the second time
- **Recoil**, both veritical and horizontal
- **Min and Max Spread** of bullets, while standing, crouching, or prone; moving or standing still; and zoomed or unzoomed

That same site also has

- [Diagrams of each gun's expected bullet-spread](http://symthic.com/?s=bf3&sb=plots)
  [image]
- [Charts](http://symthic.com/?s=bf3&sb=attach) on the exact effect of each attachment / [specialization](http://symthic.com/?s=bf3&sb=spec)
- A [Time to kill](http://symthic.com/?s=bf3&sb=timetokill) chart (in milliseconds) of any distance with any gun.

And [more stuff](http://symthic.com/?s=bf3&sb=vehicles) planned for the future.

Answer (score -1):

You guys should install [BETTER BATTLELOG](http://getbblog.com/) add-on (Chrome / Firefox)
It beefs up Battlelog dramatically, giving a ton of information on your stats and general information on all the weapons. And since the last 2 or 3 weeks they've included the info accessible through [bf3stats](http://bf3stats.com/).
Better Battlelog fetches data from [symthic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34140/battlefield-3-weapons-statistics-damage-etc/61552#61552)